# Passing HTML that is created as a string on the server to the client in ASP.NET Webforms without using a Literal control

Tags: asp.net, webforms, viewstate

I am generating a lot of HTML as a string in the code-behind of an ASP.NET Webforms page and setting the string to an ASP.NET Literal control like this:

```
litHTML.Text = strHtml;
```

However, I noticed that this is making the ViewState huge. Is there any cleaner/better way to pass HTML to the client from a code-behind not using an ASP.NET control?

Comment: Where are you generating the HTML? When loading the page (in Page_Load)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable ViewState for that Literal control, if ViewState is your problem (set the property **EnableViewState** of Literal control to **false**).

Comment: Not sure why I forgot all about this setting. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use an AJAX method in the client's window.onload() event that calls a web service that returns the dynamic HTML.  Then set the innerHtml property of a div to the dynamic HTML.